# Merge single PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have one PHP array which contains the content below.
Every article has an ordernumber and can have multiple group with an associated option. I want to combine the same articles in one array but all the options.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [ordernumber] => SW10001.1
        [group_name] => Typ
        [option_name] => CD-12
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ordernumber] => SW10001.1
        [group_name] => Farbe
        [option_name] => Blau
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [ordernumber] => SW10001.10
        [group_name] => Typ
        [option_name] => CD-15
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [ordernumber] => SW10001.10
        [group_name] => Farbe
        [option_name] => Rot
    )
```

I need the Arrays combined like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [ordernumber] => SW10001.1
        [options] => (
           [0] => (
              [group_name] => Typ
              [option_name] => CD-12
           )
           [1] => (
              [group_name] => Farbe
              [option_name] => Blau
           )
        )
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ordernumber] => SW10001.10
        [options] => (
           [0] => (
              [group_name] => Typ
              [option_name] => CD-15
           )
           [1] => (
              [group_name] => Farbe
              [option_name] => Rot
           )
        )
    )
```

//Edit: I just corrected the array key to non unique.

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Comment: Anything you have tried? Any code to provide?

Comment: You aren't going to be able to have multiple `[group]` keys under `[options]`. The keys in each array must be unique.

Comment: exactly. Array-keys are unique.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to be able to have multiple `[group]` keys under `[options]`. The keys in each array must be unique. But you can put them in a numerically indexed array with a simple foreach loop.

```
foreach ($your_array as $item) {
    $ordernumber = array_shift($item);
    $result[$ordernumber]['ordernumber'] = $ordernumber;
    $result[$ordernumber]['options'][] = $item;
}
```

This will produce an output like the one you're trying to get, but the keys in `[options]` will just be `0`, `1`, etc., which is probably the closest you'll be able to get to that format.